# Facebook C# SDK Recommend Post Using Access Token

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) and i want to recommend posts using offline accesing. And i try this code but it's return **The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.**

```
var client = new FacebookClient("ACCESS_TOKEN");
dynamic result = client.Post("/POST_ID/likes");
```

How can i recommend post using access_token ? Thanks for reply..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just saw another user with the same issue. It might be a bug in the SDK or with the Graph API. As a work around, you can do this.

```
var client = new FacebookClient("ACCESS_TOKEN");
dynamic throwAwayVariable = client.Get("/POST_ID/likes");
dynamic result = client.Post("/POST_ID/likes");
```

See: [POST to /likes only works after GET - bug or by design?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8875134/post-to-likes-only-works-after-get-bug-or-by-design)

Comment: No problem.  I was just looking for that post to see if I could link these two together.

Comment: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8875134/post-to-likes-only-works-after-get-bug-or-by-design

Comment: Might be a bug with the Facebook C# SDK, filed an issue as suggested by DMCS: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/workitem/5929